# Ordering an array by a value in sub-array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with lots of elements like this:

```
$items[] = array($url, $pic, $price);
```

I need $items to be sorted after $price ascending. Is there a good function to do this?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php

Comment: try to sort by key or ksort function http://hk1.php.net/ksort

Comment: This could give you a start. http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function cmp($a, $b)
  {
     return $b[2] - $a[2];
  }

     usort($item, "cmp")
```

Comment: it got sorted descending

Comment: change return $a[2]-$b[2]

Comment: Change `return $b[2] - $a[2];` with `return $a[2] - $b[2];` ...